# Find filename inside tar archive in different directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, tar

I want to write a batch script that:

- **Finds a filename**
- **The filename is inside a tar archive**
- **The tar archive is located in a different directory**
- **The filename matches a given pattern**

I want to **avoid untaring**, if possible, and want to **store the filename in a variable**.

My tar file is located in `./foo_tar`, called `bar.tar.gz`. Inside the tar archive, I want to get the filename of the file starting with `baz*`, followed by some digits and an underscore (e.g. `baz1234_`).

So far, I know of the `find` command, but it does not work when trying to access a tar file. I want something like this:

```
filename_in_question=$(find ./foo_tar/bar.tar.gz -name 'baz*')
```

Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: Does `tar ztf ./foo_tar/bar.tar.gz | grep 'baz'` do what you need?

Comment: Yes, but it does not work when assigning it to a variable `filename_in_question` (I get `qux.sh: 4: qux.sh: ztf: not found`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tar can use wildcards itself

```
tar tzvf ./foo_tar/bar.tar.gz --wildcards '*/baz*'
```

Eg.:

```
$ filename_in_question=$(tar tvf test.tar --wildcards '*/received_10205861111464136.mp4')
$ echo $filename_in_question
-rwxr-xr-x ghp/ghp 1931930 2017-11-04 10:36 ./Marieanne/Messenger/received_10205861111464136.mp4
$ echo ${filename_in_question/*\//}
received_10205861111464136.mp4
```

Comment: This does unfortunately not work when assigning it to a variable `filename_in_question` (I get `qux.sh: 4: qux.sh: tzvf: not found`)

Comment: That is because of an error in your syntax.  But I must admit, I'm a stranger to qux.sh.

Comment: I don't know if we made ourselves clear to you, @tli, but there is a syntax error in your qux.sh script.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. 

Using 
`filename_in_question=$(tar tzvf ./foo_tar/bar.tar.gz --wildcards '*/baz*')`

makes it work.

This does almost what I want. I end up getting in `filename_in_question` a string containing more information that just the filename, as it looks something like this:

`-rw-rw-r-- root/root 81 2018-02-12 10:03 foo_tar/baz1234_`

How can I extract only the last part (e.g. `baz1234_` in this case)?

Comment: ${filename_in_question/*\//} should give you that, if your fux.sh uses a sensible shell.

Comment: I am first getting the full string:

`filename_in_question=$(tar tzvf ./foo_tar/bar.tar.gz --wildcards '*/baz*')`

And then assigning:

`filename_in_question=${filename_in_question/*\//};`

But this does not work, and I get as an output `Bad substitution`.

Is the last assignment supposed to be different?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing fux.sh.  Perhaps fux sux?

Comment: Also " it looks something like this:" : it would help to know what it is really is.

Answer (score 0):

`find` only searches files that exist in the directory hierarchy, not those stored inside archives.  You can list the files with `tar -t`:

```
tar -ztf ./foo_tar/bar.tar.gz --wildcards --no-anchored 'baz*'
```

`--wildcards` allows `*` to be interpreted as a wildcard, and `--no-anchored` allows the filename to match after any `/` (so it'll still be found if it's in a subdirectory in the archive).

Pattern-matching in `tar` is not as flexible as that in `find`.  For the sort of pattern you describe, you could instead filter the complete contents through `grep`:

```
tar -ztf ./foo_tar/bar.tar.gz | grep '\(^\|/\)baz[0-9]\+_'
```

As you want to save the result in a variable, you also need to enclose the command using [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html):

```
filename_in_question=$(tar -ztf ./foo_tar/bar.tar.gz | grep '\(^\|/\)baz[0-9]\+_')
```

This would still be necessary if you were using `find`.

Comment: This does unfortunately not work when assigning it to a variable `filename_in_question` (I get `qux.sh: 4: qux.sh: -ztf: not found`)

Comment: That's a separate problem -- updated.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - your solution works, but matches more files than the ones I want to retrieve. I expanded the explanation of the specific pattern I am looking for.

Comment: @tli That's easily done by tightening the grep pattern.  Updated again.

Answer (score 0):

You need a tar implementation with built-in `libfind`:

```
star -t -f ./foo_tar/bar.tar.gz -find -name 'baz*'
```

will work as you expect and can to a lot more.

Check the schilytools tar ball: http://sourceforge.net/projects/schilytools/files/

`star` is the oldest free tar implementation. See Man page:

http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/star.1.html